# Modify confgs of many hosts at once

Tags: configuration, remote, desktop, synchronization, settings

I use two linux machines, home pc and server.

Lets say i want to modify some config files on both systems. 
How can i synchronize them to make these modifications ony once?

Is there option to add new machine to this hypotetical synchronized network and apply all previous changes to new machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a bash script that uses [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) to sync/copy your config files or folders and run it after you change something.

example:

```
$ rsync -az --progress --size-only /home/test/* server.example.com:/home/test/destination/
```

explained:

- `-a` archive, preserves all attributes like recursive ownership, timestamps, etc
- `-z` compress, saves bandwidth but is harder on your CPU so use it for slow/expensive connections only
- `--progress` shows you the progress of all the files that are being synced
- `--size-only` compare files based on their size instead of hashes (less CPU, so faster)